# Issues joining tables in GraphQL resolvers, thrown 400 error

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo-server

I am trying to join MySQL tables using GraphQL and keep receiving a 400 error code:

```
"Response not successful: Received status code 400"
```

This is how I am querying my data:

```
{
  users {
    usr_last_name
    business {
      bus_name
    }
  }
}
# or
{
  user(usr_id:1) {
    usr_last_name
    business {
      bus_name
    }
  }
}
```

Here are my resolvers for `User`.

```js
export const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        users: async() => db.user.findAll(),
        user: async(obj, args, context, info) => db.user.findByPk(args.usr_id)
    },
    Mutation: {...},
    User: {
        business: async(obj, args, context, info) => {  // This is not getting hit :/ 
           return db.business.findAll({where: {bus_user_id: args.usr_id}});
        }
    }
};
```

*(Note that I can query `Business` with no issues)*

Thanks,

Comment: A 400 status typically means your query is either malformed or otherwise invalid. Check the `errors` array inside the actual response from the server for details about what went wrong.

Comment: @DanielRearden There wasn't much information present, just a 'response was unsuccessful' : `{ "errors": [ { "message": "Response not successful: Received status code 400", "locations": [ "ServerError: Response not successful: Received status code 400
 at throwServerError (http://localhost:5001/static/js/0.chunk.js:396952:15)
 at http://localhost:5001/static/js/0.chunk.js:396975:9" ] } ] }`

Comment: Are you doing SSR? You can run the same query through GraphQL Playground to get the actual error.

Comment: I just did that and found that it provided additional information. Thank you :), resolved now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I forgot to put `business: Business` in the type definition for the type user:

```
    type User {
        usr_id: ID
        usr_first_name: String
        usr_last_name: String
        usr_email: String
        usr_password: String
        usr_create_date: Int
        usr_delete_date: Int,
        business: Business
    }
```